# Error installing ribusb gem - Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I get the following error when installing ribusb gem

[root@localhost ~]# gem install ribusb

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ribusb:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -fPIC -g -O2  -Wall  -c ribusb.c
ribusb.c:26:20: fatal error: libusb.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [ribusb.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ribusb-0.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ribusb-0.0.1/./gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a debian like system try:

`apt-get install libusb-dev`

If you have an other OS check the [libusb homepage](http://www.libusb.org/)